# Does $x^n = 1$ for all $x$ in $G$ imply that $G$ is abelian?

Tags: group-theory

Does $x^n = 1$ for all $x$ in $G$ imply that $G$ is abelian?
For $n = 2$ i know that this is correct. For odd prime numbers i know that $H_p$ (Heisenberg group modulo p) is a counter-example. But what about $n = mk$. Does this case have a counter-example too? If not, how can i go about proving this statement.

Comment: If $n$ is not a power of $2$ your Heisenberg example for a suitable $p|n$ should give you an answer.

Comment: And for powers of $2$ greater than $2$ why not look at some groups of order $8$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little bit please? (On the heisenberg part)

Comment: Well if $x^p=1$ for all $x$ then $x^{pN}=1$ for all $x$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks! About the powers of 2: i dont know any non-abelian groups of order 8 except for $S_8$ and $H_8$.

Comment: I just realized what happened. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and suppose $n>2$. Does there exist a non-abelian group $G$ in which $x^n=1$ for all $x\in G$? The answer is **Yes**.

For an odd prime $p$ you know that $H_p$ satisfies $x^p=1$ for all $x$.

For $n=4$ the Dihedral group $D_8$ of order $8$ (or the quaternion group) satisfies $x^4=1$ for all $x$.

Now let $n>4$. If $n$ is divisible by an odd prime $p$ so that $n=pk$, then the Heisenberg group $H_p$ satisfies $x^n=(x^{p})^k=1$ for all $x$.

If $n=2^k$ and $k\geqslant 2$ then $D_8$ satisfies $(x^4)^{2^{k-2}}=1$.

Comment: Although, in the last part it should be $k\ge2$. Just clarifying a typo.

Comment: Sorry, changed  now

Answer (score 4):

I know this answer is not complete, but you can consider $S_3$ or $D_3$: the order and the esponent of the group are 6, but the group is non abelian.

Comment: But in $S_3$, the hypothesis that "$x^n=1$ for all $x$ in $G$" does not hold.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your hypothesis

Comment: The $n$ in the hypothesis is a fixed $n$.

Comment: Well if $n=6$ then my comment could be a counter example, am I wrong?

Comment: Yes it is. I was thinking about n<6.

Answer (score 3):

Take any finite group of order $n$. Then $x^n=1$ for every $x\in G$. So all you have to do is find (if it exists) a non-abelian group of order $n$. For example [the quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ is non-abelian and $x^8=1$ for all $x\in Q_8$.

Comment: I know but im stuck on the "how" part.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri "how" what? There are **lots** of counterexamples. You can't prove the statement.

Comment: By "how" i mean how do i construct a counter-example.

Comment: What about other powers of 2?

Comment: @ShervinSorouri $Q_8\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{2^n}$.

Comment: Nice! Good idea.